# Reveal jquery modal overlay video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

For some reason, using reveal jquery modal works great with firefox and chrome, but when using internet explorer a video embedded overlays the popup, can anybody give an idea? I tried the suggested z-index but it didn't do anything.

This is the way I am using it:
    
      
       $(function() {
        $('#myModal').reveal();
       });

```
  <style>
    #imagenPopup
     {
       max-height:450px;
       display: block;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto
       overflow:auto;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <img id="imagenPopup" img src="imagenPrincipal/imagen.png" alt="">
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  </div>

    <div class="video_home">
        <object width="320" height="170"><param name="movie"              
          value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ye39lijJPC0?version=3&amp;hl=es_ES&amp;rel=0">
          </param>
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
          <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
          <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ye39lijJPC0?version=3&amp;hl=es_ES&
          amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="170" 
          allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
        </object>
    </div>

</body>
```

This is an example of the problem: http://s30.postimg.org/q0abbphq9/imagen.png
(Sorry, SO won't allow me to post images yet)

Comment: This might help: http://ageekandhisblog.com/how-to-fix-internet-explorer-youtube-video-showing-above-fixed-element-ignoring-z-index/

Answer (score 0):

Your modal have not z-index property. The style of modal shoud be:

```
#imagenPopup
 {
   max-height:450px;
   display: absolute;
   top:10%;
   left:50%;
   translate:transformX(-50%);
   z-index:200;
 }
```

Comment: For some reason z-index is not working; but now I think could be something related to a old implementation of lightbox in the project